# launch chrome instead firefox when start H2

Tags: h2

When start H2 database in server mode, at the same time it's open firefox to acces web interface.
I want to be launched chrome instead, but i don't know how.
I use Linux Mint. As preferred browser is set to google-chrome.
This is not very incovenient but if can be change that, will be ok.

Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Ubuntu (you must specify correct path to `h2.jar`):

```
$ java -Dh2.browser=google-chrome -jar h2.jar
```

Looking at the source of `org.h2.tools.Server.openBrowser()` the library tries to open any browser from the list below in that order, ignoring system default:

```
String[] browsers = 
  { "firefox", "mozilla-firefox", "mozilla", "konqueror", "netscape", "opera" };
```

Comment: Thanks! I will add `google-chrome` to this list (at the very beginning). By the way, H2 first tries to open the default browser (using `java.awt.Desktop.browse`), and only if this doesn't work it will use the list above. But specifying the browser in using `java -Dh2.browser=google-chrome` overrides all that.